# error while slicing in list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, slice

For a list x of lists, when I want to get the first member of all the lists in x, I type x[:][0]. But it gives me the first list in x. Can someone explain why this is so?

Here is an example.

```
x=[[1,2],[3,4]]
print x[0][:]
print x[:][0]
```

I get same answer for both `x[:][0]` and `x[0][:]` I get the same answer, namely `[1,2]`.
I am using Python 2.6.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `[x[0] for x in nested]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x[:]` just returns the contents of x.  So `x[:][0]` is the same as `x[0]`.  There is no built-in support for slicing a list of lists "vertically".  You have to use a list comprehension as suggested by @squiguy's comment.

Answer (score 1):

`x[:]` simply creates a shallow copy of `x`. For this reason, `x[:][0]` is the same as `x[0][:]` (both are the same as `x[0]`).

Numpy is perfect for what you're trying to do, though.

```
x = numpy.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
x[:,0]
x[0,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
x=[[1,2],[3,4]]
print x[0][0]
print x[1][0]
```

or

```
for child in x:
    print child[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement @BrenBarn answer, to solve your problem you could use:

```
first_numbers = [l[0] for l in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the below statements

```
print x[:][1]

or

print x[1][:]

or

print x[1]
```

all produces the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You are *almost* using the numpy syntax

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> x[:,0]
array([1, 3])
```

If you want to do tricky things with arrays, consider whether you should be using numpy